# iOS: Simple Local Notification 3 Days Prior

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, nsdate, local

I wrote an app that allows the user to enter a date on a date picker, and then when they tap a button it will schedule a local notification. The only issue is, the notification fires right when I tap the button. Any help is much appreciated! Here is my code:

```
 - (IBAction)scheduleNotifButton:(id)sender {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:-3];

NSDate *targetDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];

        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif == nil)
            return;
        localNotif.fireDate = targetDate;
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        localNotif.alertBody = @"Event is in 3 days!";
        localNotif.alertAction = nil;

        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:]` instead:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:-3];

NSDate *targetDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];

[dateComponents release];

...
```

Comment: Just replace all of your dateComponents stuff with that code, and then use targetDate to set up your local notification.

Comment: Also, as a side note, it might be worth checking that `targetDate` is later than the current date. I'm not sure what the behaviour is when you try and schedule a local notification in the past.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Although the notification didn't fire, should I update the OP with my current code?

Comment: Have you checked the date it was registered for? Just do `NSLog(@"%@", targetDate);` to check it

Comment: Awesome thanks man. The fire date is correct in the console, but when I check the notification center, it appears to have fired right when I clicked the button. I may have messed something up in my code, should I update my OP with my current code?

Comment: It might be worth posting another question if you're having trouble with local notifications.

Comment: Cool thank you for all your help. I'll update this one and create another question. Thanks again!

Comment: Concerning your side note: From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html): If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the notification is delivered immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for complete code on how to schedule a notification a bit later (like say 3 seconds) here's the complete code :

NOTE : If you're inside the app you won't see a message box at the top of the screen, that might have to be handled through the UIApplication delegate.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setSecond: 3 ];

NSDate *targetDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];

localNotification.fireDate = targetDate;

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotification.alertBody = @"Notified";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```